# Loop in a json codeigniter object with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I searched in many questions but doesn't worked for me, I want to loop through a json object returned by a controller, let me show you the code:

**MODEL**

```
public function traer_pasajero($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('pasajeros');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function traer_pasajero(){
$pasajero = $this->pasajeros_model->traer_pasajero($this->input->post('id'));
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($pasajero));
return $pasajero;
}
```

**JS**

function modificarPasajero (id) {

```
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://localhost/xxx/xxx/traer_pasajero", 
     data: {id: id},
     dataType: "text",  
     cache:false,
     success: 
          function(data){

            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
            alert(value);
            });
          }
     });
```

}

And I receive this error in firebug:
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

This is the json object that I see in firebug:

[{"id":"1","primer_nombre":"xxxx","segundo_nombre":"","primer_apellido":"xxxx","segundo_apellido":"","ci":"xxx","nacionalidad":"Uruguayo","fecha_nacimiento":"5/7/1910","vencimiento":"5/5/1910","asiento":"12","habitacion":"Sgl","levante":"","telefono":"","observaciones":"","id_envio":"2"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataType` should be `"json"` instead of `"text"`, and try to `console.log(data)` before each loop.

Comment: [Object { id="1", primer_nombre="xxx", primer_apellido="xxx", más...}]
shows me that but how I can iterate?

Comment: Ok, JSON response looks fine. Iterate it as you already tried with $.each(data, function( key, value ) { ... });

Comment: I made  alert(value) inside the each and return [object Object], thats ok ?

Comment: Yes, that't expected behavior for alert() function. If you want to see your data, try to console.log('Key: '+key+', Value: '+value); This is the point where you should do something with that data, for example show it to user or whatever. Check jQuery functions like $(selector).html() and $(selector).append() for example...

Comment: I use 
                 $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                      alert(element.primer_nombre); 
                      $('#primer_nombre').val(element.primer_nombre)
                  });

And work!

Comment: Ok, as I'm typing you already found the solution :) Note that index and element could be named whatever, but then you have to use the exact names inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

try removing this statement

```
 return $pasajero;
```

as it is overwriting your json..
you can simply return

```
 return json_encode($pasajero);
```

and then try 
also cahnge

```
datatype : "json"
```

now to iterate you can use eval(string) or JSON.parse(string). but note that eval is dangerous

```
   var obj = eval("("+data+")");
```

or

```
   var obj = parseJSON(data);  
  $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
        alert(value);
        });
```

Comment: parseJson is not defined

Comment: parseJSON  in JSON always in capital

Comment: you can also use eval one, as you know what are you sending but when you dont know thn avoid eval, in this case its okay :)